# JQuery Form submission handling does not work

Tags: html, jquery

i am currently trying to code a contact form jQuery submission handling but somehow my code does not work. Apparently i had a misconception but i don't know where.

So after submitting the form there should appear an success alert or an error alert, but nothing happens and i don't know why.

```js
$(function() {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {

      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();

    } else {

      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

    }
  }

  $('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);

    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: './php/handler.php',
      data: formdata,
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="p-3" id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="card-header px-4 py-sm-2 py-3">
    <h2>Ich freue mich auf Ihre Anfrage!</h2>
    <p class="lead"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body pt-1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 pe-2 mb-3">
        <label>* Vor- und Zuname:</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="z.B. Max Mustermann" type="text" required id="name">
      </div>

      <div class="mb-4">
        <label>* E-Mail Adresse:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="z.B. max.muster@gmail.com" required id="email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-4">
        <label>Telefonnummer: </label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" class="form-control" placeholder="z.B. +43 012 0123456" id="number">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 pe-2 mb-3">
        <label>* Betreff:</label>
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Ihr Betreff ..." type="text" required id="messagehead">
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12 pe-2 mb-3">
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
          <label>* Anfrage:</label>
          <textarea name="message" class="form-control border-radius-lg" id="message" rows="6" placeholder="Ihre Anfrage ..." required id="messagebody"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <label>Laden Sie hier Ihre Datei hoch:</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 text-start py-0">
        <input name="image" type="file" id="file" class="form-control btn-primary bg-gradient-primary">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 text-end ms-auto py-0 pb-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary bg-gradient-primary mb-0" id="submit">Abschicken</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert" id="success_message" style="display: none;">
  <span class="alert-text"><strong>Erfolg!</strong> Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich gesendet!</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show mt-5" role="alert" id="error_message" style="display: none;">
  <span class="alert-text"><strong>Fehler!</strong> Es trat ein Fehler auf, beim senden Ihrer Anfrage.</span>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Look in the console and see what is returned by your PHP - also add a console.log(): `function after_form_submitted(data) { console.log(data)`

Comment: Start by REMOVING `id="submit"` - it can stop the form.submit

Answer (score 0):

### Add "return false;" at the bottom of JQuery submit function as below

```
$('#contact_form').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $form = $(this);
    var formdata = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: './php/handler.php',
      data: formdata,
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false
    });

return false;
});
```